# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "extra" of relation "units_unit" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I'm getting a strange error that I can't find information for. The error occurs for app 'units' on my site deployed on Heroku; it doesn't happen locally. It is as if Django has created a table column that I'm not allowed to access?

models.py:

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    div_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    div_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    unit_hierarchy = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

To demonstrate the error, I'll try to create an instance:

```
>>> from units.models import Unit
>>> x=Unit(div_number='1st',div_type='Infantry',unit_hierarchy='Division',nationality='Canada')
>>> x
<Unit: Canada 1st Infantry Division>
```

But then `x.save()` gives the following error traceback.

```
>>> x.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "extra" of relation "units_unit" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (118, 1st, Infantry, Division, Canada, null).


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "extra" of relation "units_unit" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (118, 1st, Infantry, Division, Canada, null).
```

It's as if it's looking for a non-nullable column "extra", but I don't know anything about such a column. The usual fix for this is to set the column `null=True`. But when I run the following migration:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('units', '0005_location_is_valid'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='unit',
            name='extra',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

I get the following error traceback:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying units.0006_auto_20210524_1646...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 608, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'extra'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 240, in database_forwards
    from_field = from_model._meta.get_field(self.name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 610, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Unit has no field named 'extra'
```

Appreciate any help and let me know if there is other information.

Comment: You probably have some kind of desynchronization between your models/migration and the actual database state. If you're able to do so, connect to the database directly and inspect the table for mentioned model.

Comment: Yup - you were right. It was not easy to get into the database, but was able to kill the column once I did and seems to work fine now. Thanks!